# For loop in UML activity diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm looking for a package/code snippet to have this kind of diagram. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Any code so far?

Comment: I have a "flowchart" for now, which has a `for` loop, but it's not how we want it. I can draw the inside boxes, and arrows, but I have no idea how to make that dashed external box with two inside horizontal lines in a proper way, and not having a box + two lines in the middle of the code, hard coded.

Comment: Have a look at [the TikZ-PGF manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), for instance at the `shape` library (Section 67, p. 701).

Comment: Use `fit` library to draw the external box giving it a name like `(foo)`, and then interpolated coordinates for the horizontal lines in the form `($(foo.north west)!.3333!(foo.south west)$)` to denote (in this case) the point at 1/3 of the way from the upper left corner to the lower left corner of that external box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the comments and some other sources, I managed to have something which draws what I want, but I bet it's not perfect. I put it here for people who might have the same question, hope it's helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{entity} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, rounded corners, -latex']

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4em, auto]
  \node [block] (phi_l) {\footnotesize $\Phi_l \leftarrow \{\}$};
  \node [block, below of=phi_l, text width = 7em, node distance = 5em] (i) {\footnotesize $i \leftarrow 0$};
  \node [block, below of=i, text width = 7em] (i_inc) {\footnotesize $i < N$};
  \node [block, below of=i_inc, text width=12em] (fit_li) {\footnotesize $l_i \leftarrow \text{L1-SVM}(X_{-\Phi_l}, y)$};
  \node [block, below of=fit_li, text width=7em] (up_phi) {\footnotesize $\Phi_l \leftarrow \Phi_l \cup \Phi_{l_i}$};
  \path [line] (fit_li) -- (up_phi);
  \node [block, below of=up_phi] (inc_i) {\footnotesize $i \leftarrow i + 1$};
  \path [line] (up_phi) -- (inc_i);

  \node [block, below of=inc_i, node distance = 5em] (f) {\footnotesize $f \in \Phi_{l_i}$};
  \node [block, below of=f, text width = 13em, node distance = 5em] (phi_f) {\footnotesize$\Phi_f \leftarrow \text{TOP}\left\{ \left( f', \text{MI}\left(f,f'\right)\right) \ri\
ght\} $};
  \node [block, below of=phi_f, text width=10em] (g_f) {\footnotesize $g_f \leftarrow \text{GP}(X_{\Phi_f}, f)$};
  \path [line] (phi_f) -- (g_f);

  \node [block, dashed, fit={($(f.north)+(0,1em)$) (phi_f) (g_f)}] (for2) {};
  \node at (for2.north west) [below right] {for};
  \node [block, dashed, fit={($(i.north)+(0,1em)$) (phi_f) (g_f) (for2) (inc_i)}] (for1) {};
  \node at (for1.north west) [below right] {for};

  \path [draw, dashed] ($(for1.north west)!.13!(for1.south west)$) -- ($(for1.north east)!.13!(for1.south east)$);
  \coordinate (coordinate1) at ($(for1.north west)!.13!(for1.south west)$);
  \node at (coordinate1.east) [below right] {while};
  \path [draw, dashed] ($(for1.north west)!.23!(for1.south west)$) -- ($(for1.north east)!.23!(for1.south east)$);
  \coordinate (coordinate2) at ($(for1.north west)!.23!(for1.south west)$);
  \node at (coordinate2.east) [below right] {do};

  \path [draw, dashed] ($(for2.north west)!.32!(for2.south west)$) -- ($(for2.north east)!.32!(for2.south east)$);
  \coordinate (coordinate3) at ($(for2.north west)!.32!(for2.south west)$);
  \node at (coordinate3.east) [below right] {do};

  \node at ($(for1.north west)!{(1 * 1/2)}!(for1.north east)$) [entity, fill=white] (phi_l_entity) {\footnotesize $\Phi_l$};
  \node at ($(for1.north west)!{(1 * 1/4)}!(for1.north east)$) [entity, fill=white] (X_entity) {\footnotesize $X$};
  \node at ($(for1.north west)!{(3 * 1/4)}!(for1.north east)$) [entity, fill=white] (y_entity) {\footnotesize $y$};
  \path [line] (phi_l) -- (phi_l_entity);

  \node at ($(for2.north west)!{(1 * 1/3)}!(for2.north east)$) [entity, fill=white] (X_entity2) {\footnotesize $X$};
  \node at ($(for2.north west)!{(2 * 1/3)}!(for2.north east)$) [entity, fill=white] (phi_li_entity) {\footnotesize $\Phi_{l_i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]